# How to stop find after a certain number of results

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make certain that a specific directory has at least 100 files of at least 1MB each. The search has to be recursive because there are many sub-directories. I cannot wait until I get a list of all >1Mb files because the directory has millions of files and it would take too long.

So I expected the following command to work :

```
find -size +1M | head -n 100
```

There are plenty of files over 1Mb in my directory so it should take only seconds before the `head` command returns with the list of the first 100 lines. But it takes a lot longer.

If I run `find -size +1M` it takes a very short time to get many results. Even more so when it's run two times in a row and the the FS cache is fresh.

So I wonder why `head` doesn't return as soon as the first 100 files are found.

On the other hand, if I omit the "-size" parameter, it works just fine :

`find | head -n 100`

This returns immediately with a list of 100 files.

I am running GNU/Linux Debian 7.4 (Wheezy) with kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64. Filesystem is ext4 on top of an LVM volume on a single RAID1 array. It has 9638853 used inodes (6%), a capacity of 2.7 Tb and 682 Gb free.

Comment: This question is not really about programming and should be moved to [SU], or maybe to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: That said, I wonder why you're using Debian 7.4. Any particular reason? Your basic regular updates should have taken you to 7.8 by now.

Comment: You are right, it's not about programming. Sorry about that.

Comment: And yes, I am a few upgrades behind for no particular reason. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how pipes work. It waits until output of `find -size +1M` fills the pipe buffer, then pipes it to `head -n 100`, so you are actually waiting for the `find` command to fill the pipe buffer which is usually 64 kilobytes.

When you omit the `-size` parameter, the results come out really quickly, it just takes time to print all the lines in your terminal so it is perceived as taking a longer time.

If you run `find -size +1M` alone, it takes a short time to get many results, but not *all* results. If you let it run towards completion, you will see that it will take a long time too.

You can use `stdbuf` to modify buffering operations for a certain command. For example,

```
stdbuf -oL -eL find -size +1M | head -n 10
```

will line-buffer stdout and stderr for your command, and the results should come out faster.

Comment: How can you explain the fact that running `find` takes minutes and `find | head -n 100` less than one second ? If I understand your first sentence correctly, it should take the same time ("waiting for the find command to finish executing").

Comment: But the you mention the stdout buffer. This is interesting. Is there a way to make it smaller so it fills quickly and head would return faster ?